# Creating a footer in SSRS Report Builder Vs. 2016 without using the standard Footer function "Make footer"

Tags: reporting-services, report, reporting, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder

i need to create a footer that can stay at the bottom of every pages of the report, but i can't use the standard function because i need to hide some element before it self.

I hope that i've explained correctly!
Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you should be able to do this by creating rectangles to hold your report content.

If you need a header, body and footer then you would need 3 rectangles, if you only need the main body and a footer then 2 rectangles.

For simplicity, let's say you page is 29cm high and the bottom 6cm will contain the footer.

You create a rectangle that is 23cm high and wide enough to hold the elements you need in it. Then your seconds rectangle immediately below will be 6cm.

Within each rectangle, place you report elements (text boxes, tables etc).

Note: If you already have the report elements in your report, do not drag them over the rectangle as this will literally overlay them, instead, select everything you ned, then cut them. Then click in the rectangle to make it active and paste them, this way the rectangle will be the container. If you are creating the elements from new then you can add them within the rectangle as normal.

Once all your body and footer elements are in position, change the 'ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace' property of Report to `true`. This property will prevent the rectangle from expanding as the number of rows in a table gets larger, as it will use the space in the container first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try with this solution and i'll let you know about the result. I will try with two rectangles: Body and Footer and i'll paste the textboxes inside of these rectangles  and add the property to the report.